# pd.pivot: tidy to wide dataframe conversion error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I am trying to convert a "tidy" dataframe (df1) to "wide" dataframe as a desired result using the pd.pivot function but running into issues.

The tidy dataframe can be recreated using the below code segment:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"stud_id": ['1234', '1234', '1234', '1234', '1234', '1234', '1234', '1234','1234', '1234', '1234', '1234',
                     '8076', '8076', '8076', '8076', '8076', '8076', '8076', '8076', '8076'],
"period":['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4','Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4',
         'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
"subject": ['clay', 'clay', 'clay', 'clay', 'feat', 'feat', 'feat', 'feat','tabl', 'tabl', 'tabl', 'tabl',
           'clay', 'clay', 'clay', 'feat', 'feat', 'feat', 'tabl', 'tabl', 'tabl'],
"score": [0.05, 0.05, 0.09, 0.03, 0.05, 0.45, 0.3, 0.2, 0.8, 0.56, 0.72, 0.72,
          0, 0.1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.8, 0, 0]
               })
```

The "desired result" should look like this:

[image]

I have mostly attempted to get the desired result using pd.pivot with little success. Example code & value error I get shown below:

```
df1.pivot(index=['stud_id', 'period'], columns='subject', values=['score'])
Value Error: Shape of passed values is (1, 21), indices imply (1, 2)`
```

As an alternative, I tried below code that also resulted in an error as follows:

```
df1.pivot(index='stud_id', columns='subject', values=['score'])
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Can somebody please guide me towards the solution?

Comment: `df1.pivot(index=['stud_id', 'period'], columns='subject', values=['score'])` gives the desired output for the provided sample on my end.

Comment: That is strange and interesting @Henry. I am still getting the same error on my end. Hope there is an option without using pd.pivot - especially - if it is not stable across versions?

Comment: This actually worked for me:`pd.pivot_table(df1, index=['stud_id', 'period'], columns='subject', values=['score'])`                                                                       
 Perhaps the package name has changed? However, it requires collapsing multiple indexes and not a clean solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pivot` is the same as adding indexes and then stacking or unstacking appropriately. Which means it can also be used as a workaround:

```
>>> df1.pivot(index=['stud_id', 'period'], columns='subject', values='score').reset_index()
subject stud_id period  clay  feat  tabl
0          1234     Q1  0.05  0.05  0.80
1          1234     Q2  0.05  0.45  0.56
2          1234     Q3  0.09  0.30  0.72
3          1234     Q4  0.03  0.20  0.72
4          8076     Q2  0.00  0.50  0.80
5          8076     Q3  0.10  0.50  0.00
6          8076     Q4  0.00  0.00  0.00
>>> df1.set_index(['stud_id', 'period', 'subject'])['score'].unstack('subject').reset_index()
subject stud_id period  clay  feat  tabl
0          1234     Q1  0.05  0.05  0.80
1          1234     Q2  0.05  0.45  0.56
2          1234     Q3  0.09  0.30  0.72
3          1234     Q4  0.03  0.20  0.72
4          8076     Q2  0.00  0.50  0.80
5          8076     Q3  0.10  0.50  0.00
6          8076     Q4  0.00  0.00  0.00
```

Note that if you replace the column `'score'` with the list of columns `['score']` you get a multi-index as columns − that might be the issue.

In any case, if you have more than one cell in the original dataframe mapped to a single frame in the latter, you get the `Index contains duplicate entries`, and need to use `pivot_table`. Here you’ll choose a function to aggregate these cells (by default `aggfunc=np.mean`):

```
>>> df1.pivot_table(index='stud_id', columns='subject', values='score')
subject      clay      feat      tabl
stud_id                              
1234     0.055000  0.250000  0.700000
8076     0.033333  0.333333  0.266667
>>> df1.pivot_table(index='stud_id', columns='subject', values='score', aggfunc='min')
subject  clay  feat  tabl
stud_id                  
1234     0.03  0.05  0.56
8076     0.00  0.00  0.00
```

Comment: Truly beautiful explanation and super elegant code for your alternative to df.pivot: `df1.set_index(['stud_id', 'period', 'subject'])['score'].unstack('subject').reset_index()`.  Thank you so much Cimbali!